# My div forms are aligned properly

Tags: asp.net

I hav desgined a form of personal information for my website but the input is floating towards right instead of left. Please help me and suggest if to use tables or Divs is better ?? I am making website on resort for project .

```
 <div id="main">
 <h1 id="availH1">Online Reservation- Select Room</h1>
  <div id="availRight">
                <div id="availStatus">
                <p >Check Availability</p>
                <p>Select Room </p>
                <p class="checkAvail">Enter Details </p>    
                <p>Review Reservation & Confirm</p>        
                </div>

 <div id="reguser">
  <table  id="regtable" width="600" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" colspan="6" ><div align="left">Registered User Login</div></th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">Registered users please enter information below</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Email id:</th>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                 </td>
    <th>Password</th>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                 </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                                 </td>
    <td>Forgot Password?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
 </div>



<div id="Personal">
            <h1>Personal Details</h1>
        <label class="Plabel">Title:    
         <span class="personal">Enter the Title</span>
        </label>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="cboTitle" width="200" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem>Mr.</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Mrs.</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Miss.</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>

        <label class="Plabel">First Name:
        <span class="personal">Enter your First Name</span>
        </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="CtxtName" class="Ptxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <label class="Plabel">Last Name:
        <span class="personal">Enter your last Name</span>
        </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" class="Ptxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <label  class="Plabel">Address:
        <span class="personal">Enter your Residential Address</span>
        </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd" class="Ptxt" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

        <label  class="Plabel">City:
        <span class="personal">Enter your City</span>
        </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" class="Ptxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <label  class="Plabel">Pincode:
        <span class="personal">Enter your Pincode</span>
        </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPincode" class="Ptxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <label  class="Plabel">State:
        <span class="personal">Enter your State</span>
        </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" class="Ptxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <label  class="Plabel">Contact Number:
        <span class="personal">Enter your Contact Number</span>
        </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtContact" class="Ptxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


        <label  class="Plabel">Email Address:
        <span class="personal">Enter your Email address</span>
        </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" class="Ptxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <label  class="Plabel">Password:
        <span class="personal">Enter your Password</span>
        </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" class="Ptxt" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="PbtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

    </div>
    </div>


    </div>
```

css-----

```
#reguser { width:700px; margin-bottom:10px;}
#regtable { margin:20px 0 20px 20px;}
#cboTitle { padding:5px; width:200px; margin:2px 0px 20px 10px; float:left;}

#Personal { width:400px;
               padding:15px; height:534px;
}


#Personal{border:solid 2px #b7ddf2;
                background:#FFE87C;
                margin-top:25px;
                 margin-left:200px;}

#Personal h1 {font-size:24px;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    margin-bottom:8px;}


.Plabel {display:block;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        text-align:right;
                        width:140px;
                        float:left;}

.personal {color:#666666;
                            display:block;
                            font-size:11px;
                            font-weight:normal;
                            text-align:right;
                            width:140px;}

.Ptxt {float:left;
                            font-size:12px;
                            padding:4px 2px;
                            border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
                            width:200px;
                            margin:2px 0 20px 10px;}

#PbtnSubmit{clear:both;
                        margin-left:150px;
                        width:125px;
                        height:31px;

                        text-align:center;
                        line-height:31px;
                        color:#FFFFFF;
                        font-size:11px;
                        font-weight:bold;}
.spacer {clear:both; height:1px;}

#ContactForm p, #ContactForm h1, #ContactForm form, #ContactForm ,Button{border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your Personal css to below code

```
 <style type="text/css">

        #reguser
        {
            width: 700px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;

        }
        #regtable
        {
            margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
        }
        #cboTitle
        {
            padding: 5px;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 2px 0px 20px 10px;
            float: right;
        }
        #Personal
        {
            width: 400px;
            padding: 15px;
            height: 570px;
            float: left;
            text-align: left;
            border: solid 2px #b7ddf2;
            background: #FFE87C;
            margin-top: 25px;

        }
        #Personal h1
        {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }
        .Plabel
        {
            display: block;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: right;
            width: 140px;
            float: left;
        }
        .personal
        {
            color: #666666;
            display: block;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-align: right;
            width: 140px;
        }
        .Ptxt
        {
            float: right;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 4px 2px;
            border: solid 1px #aacfe4;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 2px 0 20px 10px;
        }
        #PbtnSubmit
        {
           clear: both; 
            margin-left: 190px;
            width: 125px;
            height: 31px;
            position: relative; 
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 31px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: bold; 

        }
        .spacer
        {
            clear: both;
            height: 1px;
        }
        #ContactForm p, #ContactForm h1, #ContactForm form, #ContactForm, Button
        {
            border: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

        }
    </style>
```

hope this helps ....

Comment: its floating to the left but all the text boxes are floating left and labels to its right dats what the prob  is :(

Comment: hey thanx for helping but the button is going at top ,, but i liked ur quick response thanks a lot for helping me .